# How to extract street graph or network from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: networking, graph, openstreetmap, osmnx, overpass-api

How to extract street graph or network from OpenStreetMap ?

Comment: Have you looked at the osmium tool?  https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solutions:

There are many solutions to achieve this goal, I listed some of them below.

### - [Overpass-api](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)

Overpass-api & overpass-turbo let you use overpass query language to collect [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) and [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node) of type [highway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway) for a city :

```
[out:xml]; area[name = "Pantin"]; (way(area)[highway]; ); (._;>;); out;
```

> Pantin is a city in France
> [image: overpass-turbo]

### - [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) & [Osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html)

Geofabrik allows you to download various datasets from continents to cities.

Next, extract nodes and ways of type highway using **Osmium tag-filters**:

```sh
osmium tags-filter map.osm w/highway -o highways-ways.osm
```

> ***NOTE:*** osmium tags-filter also works with .pbf files

### - [Ophois](https://github.com/ethicnology/ophois)

Ophois is a CLI tool written in Rust, i created to:

- Download a map from overpass-api
- Process data from Overpass or Geofabrik to extract the street graph
- Simplify the extracted graph with detailed heuristics
- Discretize the extracted or simplified graph to a distance in meter

I also created a simple tool to display the generated graph on a Leaflet map  to check the simplification process, **[cartographe](https://ethicnology.github.io/cartographe/)**.
**Cartographe** let you check the node id and the distance of links in meters using [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

#### Extracted

[image: Pantin extracted from overpass-api using Ophois]

#### Simplified

[image: Pantin simplified using Ophois]

#### Simplified and Discretized

[image: Pantin simplified and discretized using Ophois]

> **NOTE:** Simplified and discretized with 10 meters parameter

### - [OSMnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx)

OSMnx: Python for street networks. Retrieve, model, analyze, and visualize street networks and other spatial data from OpenStreetMap.
[image: Pantin-osmnx]

> **NOTE:** Pantin using OSMnx

Comment: AWESOME! I want to add other three options,

1. [osm2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting)
2. [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/)
3. [osm4routing2](https://github.com/Tristramg/osm4routing2)

Comment: I am also wondering if you could use any of these tools for big graph extraction, eg, for the whole planet.

Comment: @kangkang
When I composed [ophois](https://github.com/ethicnology/ophois), I designed it to process streams of data so it can perform big graphs.

You can download datasets of big regions [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/). For the whole earth you should concatenate and maybe pre-process these datasets